# Why all Angular 2.0 DI API is marked as @deprecated?

Tags: angular, angular2-di

Searching into Angular 2.0 source code (`@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.4`) I found that first it contains two `provider.d.ts` definitions this is one aspect but other aspect is that all the classes in this `provider.d.ts` files and a lot of properties are marked as `@deprecated`.

```
node_modules\@angular\core\src\di\provider.d.ts

node_modules\@angular\core\esm\src\di\provider.d.ts
```

I was looking on how to use Angular 2.0 DI outside of Angular Components. Since Angular 2.0 is in quite advanced state(Release Candidate) most of the API should be already stable with some minor changes possibly coming. Still all of this classes related in DI are marked as deprecated. In the same time all tutorials and examples in internet are with classes from this provider.d.ts files my question is. What this `@deprecated` flag means and should I use the API's in this provider.d.ts files or not ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the new way of adding non-primitive providers is object literal syntax like

```
providers: [MyMockClass, {provide: MyClass, useExisting: MyMockClass}]
```

`useValue`, `useFactory`, `useClass`, `multi` are also parameters that are supported in addition to `useExisting`.